# Should one keep track of workouts and if so how?

Tags: workout

To get fit in the gym / lifting weights, is it important to keep track of how much weight you lift, which exercises you do on which days? What's wrong with going by feel? What are the advantages of keeping track on paper as opposed to an app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your goals, but if you're shooting for:

- Balanced exercises that will not hurt you.
- The most productive use of your time.
- Building strength, power, and muscle size.
- Avoidance of over-use injuries.

I would recommend following a *program*. Unless you were an Olympic trainer in a past life, the reality is that other people (professional trainers and coaches) know what you should do more than you do. As such, follow the advice that has been laid out in advance, for free, by these professionals.

So to answer your question directly, you should not only keep track of what you do but you should also be following a plan of exactly what to do. What exercises, how many times, how much force/weight, how much time, etc.

I would recommend [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) or [Strong Lifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/); there is no way you're going to have comparable results coming up with your own plan.

Edit, I found an old training plan that I used for weeks on the [Madcow 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/madcow/5x5_Program/Linear_5x5.htm) program (for [intermediate lifters](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.htm)). For me I carried this around with a pen, and would make little notes about injuries, missed weights, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The situations where keeping track is better than not include

- being away from a lift for a long time and forgetting how much you can do
- having a short memory but wanting to do more than you did last time for progressive overload, or the same routine you did last time
- wondering if your program is working and being able to look back to see if you've stalled
- getting motivation by looking at your milestones and how far you've come.

The situations where an app like [Fitocracy](https://www.fitocracy.com/home/) or  [MapMyRun](http://www.mapmyrun.com/my_home/) is better than a paper diary are

- wanting automatic tracking of milestones and PRs, with charts and quests
- wanting other people to see your workouts for getting motivation from the community
- when you do similar workouts and can repeat them instead of writing things out.
- when the app can track your miles, steps, times, or sets automatically.

The situations where paper is better include

- when you have no suitable pockets or places to set a phone
- when you want to leave your record at the gym

I recommend tracking. There's always time for it in between sets.